# C Plus Plus: Calculating the area of Rectangle and Triangle

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm writing a program that shows a shape of rectangle and triangle, and computes the area of those shapes.I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio. These is my codes:

I have four codes and the image of errors list: Shapes.h, shapesfunchtions3.h, shapes3.cpp, and testshapes3.cpp

[Mediafire Folder of my four codes](http://www.mediafire.com/folder/a72u1zv1kq086/Shapes3)

But I get this errors: Any solution to this?

if you can't see the image of the errors list, then it is this:

Error   1

error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall Shapes::DisplayMenu(void)" (?DisplayMenu@Shapes@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function "public: char __thiscall Shapes::SelectShape(void)" (?SelectShape@Shapes@@QAEDXZ)    C:\Users\Eduardo\Documents\Mission College\Projects\shapes3\shapes3\shapes3.obj

Error   2

error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall Shapes::GetSelection(void)" (?GetSelection@Shapes@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function "public: char __thiscall Shapes::SelectShape(void)" (?SelectShape@Shapes@@QAEDXZ)  C:\Users\Eduardo\Documents\Mission College\Projects\shapes3\shapes3\shapes3.obj

Error   3

error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall Shapes::CheckSelection(void)" (?CheckSelection@Shapes@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function "public: char __thiscall Shapes::SelectShape(void)" (?SelectShape@Shapes@@QAEDXZ)  C:\Users\Eduardo\Documents\Mission College\Projects\shapes3\shapes3\shapes3.obj

Error   4

error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals   C:\Users\Eduardo\Documents\Mission College\Projects\shapes3\Debug\shapes3.exe

Comment: [See this question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You implemented this function: (You need to change this:)

```
void DisplayMenu()
{
    // ...
}
```

But it is different from: (To this:)

```
void Shapes::DisplayMenu()
{
    // ...
}
```

So do this:

```
void GetSelection()
```

and this:

```
void CheckSelection()
```

Comment: I just figure it out and fix my errors. I forgot to put void Shapes:: for DisplayMenu(), GetSelection(), CheckSelection().